# How to use pd.apply() to instantiate new columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Instead of doing this:

```
df['A'] = df['A'] if 'A' in df else None
df['B'] = df['B'] if 'B' in df else None
df['C'] = df['C'] if 'C' in df else None
df['D'] = df['D'] if 'D' in df else None
...
```

I want to do this in one line or function. Below is what I tried:

```
def populate_columns(df):
        
    col_names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', ...]
               
    def populate_column(df, col_name):
        df[col_name] = df[col_name] if col_name in df else None
        return df[col_name]
        
    df[col_name] = df.apply(lambda x: populate_column(x) for x in col_names)    
    return df
```

But I just get `Exception has occurred: ValueError`. What can I do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can replace your whole code with a [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
ensure_cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
df = df.reindex(columns=df.columns.union(ensure_cols))
```

*NB. By default the fill value is `NaN`, if you really want `None` use `fill_value=None`.*

If you want to fix your code, just use a single loop:

```
col_names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
for c in col_names:
    if c not in df:
        df[c] = None
```

Comment: I tried using fill_value=None but still returns `NaN`

Comment: @amnesic strange, indeed. Then a workaround could be: `reindex(..., fill_value='None').replace('None', None)` or use any string that you know is not in the data if `'None'` can be.

Comment: What's the point of self.df.columns.union(ensure_columns)? I can just pass in ensure columns, can't I?

Comment: It is just in case you have original columns that are not in the list.